# Missing code using gulp, babel, and uglify

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, gulp-babel

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

I'm trying to get my Javascript code on the client side to be Object-Oriented using ES6 or at least using the module pattern.

I realize that this means that it's going to need transpiled and because I'm already using gulp for other tasks, I'm trying to get Gulp to automate the transpiling for me.

**Disclaimer**

I'm not even what I'm trying to do is even possible the way I'm doing it so feel free to tell me that it's not possible.

**The Gulp File**

```
gulp.task('client', function(callback) {
    pump([
        browserify({ entries: config.js.src, debug: true })
            .transform("babelify", { presets: ["es2015"] })
            .bundle(),
        source('app.js'),
        buffer(),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest(config.js.dest),
        livereload()
    ], callback);
});
```

where `config.js.src = src/js/app.js` and `config.js.dest = public/js`

**src/js/app.js**

```
import {Rest} from './table/Rest';

class App {

    static table() {
        let rest = new Rest();
        rest.test();
        rest.testJQuery();
    }

}

App.table();
```

**src/js/table/Rest.js**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

export class Rest {

    private baseUri;

    constructor(baseUri) {
        this.baseUri = baseUri;
    }

    test() {
        console.log("Testing worked...");
    }

    testJQuery() {
        $('div').addClass('red');
    }
}
```

**Summary**

What I'm trying doesn't seem to work. I get a minified js file `public/app.js` that contains what appears to be the `require` workaround for es5 but doesn't contain any of the actual code in there. (I did a search on the word *test* in the file to if the `console.log` made it out to the file)

**Additional Information**

gulpfile.js vars:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var pump = require('pump');

var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
```

Comment: I edited the question title to reflect the actual issue. In the future please be *specific* in your question title: gulp/babel/uglify makes it pretty clear its client side, and your problem has nothing to do with object orientation.

Comment: I suppose, I was stating the end goal in the title because I was thinking about it more from an SEO perspective given what I was trying to search for. Regardless, thank you for your input